# AdSize.IAB_BANNER - no ad to show

Tags: android, admob

When I try to display my AdView with the size of an normal banner size, it works fine. But when I try to make this ad bigger, like AdSizeI.AB_BANNER, the logcat says: No ad to show.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdMob has more inventory for 320x50 than it does 468x60, so the fill rate is much lower for the IAB_BANNER size.

Also note that this size should only be used on Android Tablets.

Answer (score 2):

If you're insistent on showing that ad size, find a second ad network to join who sells ads at that size. So when adMob fails to show anything, the second ad network will pick it up, keeping your fill rate up.

Think of it sort of like a waterfall. If someone stops providing the water, you can have a back-up to help you.